# How can I get the source code of getContentPane()?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

It will be helpful if anyone can guide me on how can I get the complete source code(Documentation) of the inbuilt method getContentPane() of the JFrame class.

I want to override it in my code.

---

**Edit**:

OK heres the scene, I have two packages one with class homepage1 and other with homepage2. I'm able to access the getContentPane() in homepage2, but when I use it in homepage1 the IDE(netbeans) says unknown symbol(eventhough I have used the 'import javax.swing.*'). So if I could get the code of getContentPane(),then I want to paste it in my class 'homepage1' so that I can access it.

Comment: There's something called inheritance, why not extend the class and override the method calling first super.getContentPane()? on the other hand you can use a decompiler , or just search the code in grepcode.com, here is the code by the way... http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JFrame.java

Comment: Depends.  If you are using an IDE like NetBeans, you should be able to walk into the method (ctrl+left click in NetBeans on the method).  Otherwise browse to the location the JDK is installed and open the src.zip file.

Comment: Just download the java source code!

Comment: OK heres the scene, I have two packages one with class homepage1 and other with homepage2. I'm able to access the getContentPane() in homepage2, but when I use it in homepage1 the IDE(netbeans) says unknown symbol(eventhough I have used the 'import javax.swing.*'). So if I could get the code of getContentPane(),then I want to paste it in my class 'homepage1' so that I can access it.

Comment: *"don't ask why because it might be beyond my comprehension"*  That is a good hint **not** to do it.

Comment: You want a reference to an object to be able to use that object. So to do this you need to understand the public methods and constructors of public classes available in the package which produces that object, not the private code of the Swing library. Your way of going about this is a bit on the other side of crazy.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: no, it has nothing to do with points. He made that post out of anger because he felt that I was rude to him, and in fact I was. I have deleted the offending comments and do sincerely apologize, and I have tried to make good by answering the question to the best of my ability.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yep sorry my bad and not only ten thousand times but nearly hundred thousand times.

Comment: 1+ to the question and voting to re-open the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a classic example of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), meaning that you're asking for the solution of "X" a specific (and incorrect) way that you're trying to solve something, when what you really need is "Y", the actual solution to your actual overriding problem.

You state in comment:

> I'm able to access the getContentPane() in homepage2, but when I use it in homepage1 the IDE(netbeans) says unknown symbol(eventhough I have used the 'import javax.swing.*').

It means that you're not calling `getContentPane()` on an object that has the method, on an object that has a root pane. I'm guessing that you likely think that you're calling it on an object that is derived from JFrame, but the compiler is telling you that you're not, that the object isn't truly a JFrame.

The solution is not to dig through the source code of the Swing JFrame (or better, JRootPane which is what the JFrame method will call) but rather to either call the method on the right object, a JFrame derived object, or other JRootPane using object such as a JDialog or JApplet, or to find another way to get your object of interest by studying the classes and methods available to you in the package of interest. Sorry but your idea to solve this by looking at or using the JFrame source for `getContentPane()` will be little more than a fruitless wild goose chase, and I strongly suggest that you drop it and search for other more fruitful avenues of attack.

If you need more specific help, you'll need to tell us more about the class that harbors your object of interest, including showing us code.

Comment: thanks I'll certainly look to implement it and sorry for being rude, I was just mad at your comment. I would have voted up your answer but this question has brought my reputation down to 13 ;), so I will certainly vote it as soon as I cross the minimum mark of 15. Thanks again :)

Comment: @SaumilSoni: you're welcome, and again, sorry for the poorly made initial comments.

Comment: it's okay if you don't reply to this comment and I know I'm making this too chatty but sorry sir I wasn't aware of your age and knowledge.